# Export each record of found set to individual file?

Tags: filemaker

This seems like such a simple operation normally, but I can't seem to make FileMaker cooperate.

What I want to do:
1) Loop through each found record, one at a time.
2) Export the contents of this record to a filename based on a field within the record.

```
Loop
    Set Variable[$path; Value:Get(FilePath) & "/../somefolder" & MyTable1::my_field_1]
    Export Records [No dialog; "$path"; Unicode(UTF-8)]
End Loop
```

This script, however, appends every record to the same file.  They don't seem to offer an 'Export Record' (singular), so I'm not sure how else to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution:

```
Find All
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
  Omit
  Find Omitted
  Set Field ["HTML File Name","External("DM-Export", KeyField & ".html")"]
  Export Records [Restore]
  Find All
  Go to Record/Request/Page [Exit After Last, Next]
End Loop
```

As per Step 7 on:
http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3438/kw/exporting%20found%20set

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker's "Export Records" script step always exports the entire found set.  You must loop through the found set, and isolate each record one at a time prior to exporting:

```
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
   Set Variable[$path; Value:Get(FilePath) & "/../somefolder" & MyTable1::my_field_1]
   New Window
   Show All
   Omit Record
   Show Omitted
   Export Records [No dialog; "$path"; Unicode(UTF-8)]
   Close Window
   Go to Record/Request/Page [Exit After Last, Next]
End Loop
```